# I accidentally pushed from git to GitHub?

Tags: git

I did a `git push` in a **directory that requires security** without knowing it. Fortunately, there was no `.git` directory, but I'm worried that my **GitHub repository** might have a security-required directory on it. *Is the directory **pushed** in this case?*

Comment: Firstly, `git remote add` is a _local_ operation, it won’t upload anything anywhere. Secondly, as I understand you ran the command outside of any Git repository, so absolutely nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you did not use `git push` you are fine. You can check if your documents are uploaded by going to your Github repository if you have one.

Comment: ... And if you don't, there is no way it could have uploaded them there.